# Positioning element with jQuery does not work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, position

I have a set of images inside a div that I position with jQuery on page load.

```
var myimg = $('#myimg');
... // Calculate x and y
myimg.css('left', x);
myimg.css('bottom', y);
```

Each image has a `position: absolute` style, while their containing div has a `position: relative` style.

This works in all browsers except for Internet Explorer 8 (have not tried 9). The images do not get their positions set. I can confirm that the JavaScript is running, especially since I'm also rotating the images using [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) to rotate the images when I position them, and they appear rotated in IE.

**Edit**

This is the full JavaScript code. What I'm trying to do specifically is arrange the images in a circle.

```
var num_imgs = 14;

var angle_delta = 360 / num_imgs;

var center_x = 365;
var center_y = 245;
var radius = 230;

for (var i = 0; i < num_imgs; ++i) {
    var angle = (angle_delta * i) + 90;

    var radians = angle * 0.0174532925;
    var x = Math.round(radius * Math.cos(radians));
    var y = Math.round(radius * Math.sin(radians));

    var img = $('#myimg-' + i);
    img.rotate(90 - angle); // Only part of the code that works
    img.css('left', center_x + x);
    img.css('bottom', center_y + y);
}
```

Comment: This should work fine in IE8. Can you provide the entire, exact code you're having trouble with?

Comment: You're not using the `myimg` ID on more than one element, are you? I only ask because you said you had "a set of images".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SLgVy/2/ works correctly. Note that the image must be absolutely positioned first.

Comment: @mblase75 When I say "a set of images", I mean I iterate over each image in a for loop where the real ID is `'myimg-' + i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping each image in a `<div>` and assign your `myimg#` id to that div instead of directly to the image. Add a class to each image-containing `<div>` so that you can style them with absolute positioning all at once.

You'll need to use a little DOM traversal to get to the actual image, but that's only important for the plugin -- just use `img.children('img').rotate(90 - angle)` instead of `img.rotate(90 - angle)`. Your CSS positioning will all use the `<div>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/R86Ud/4/

Answer (score 0):

Are your x and y values simple integers, or do they have the 'px' suffix?  They should be something like '100px', not simply 100, so if you are missing the px, that could be the problem.

Comment: The `.css` method should automatically add `px` as necessary.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I've always seen 'px' used to set these types of values (as opposed to .width() and .height()), even in the jQuery examples.  Have a link?